# How to upload a text string to firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to upload my user post without a image only a post with just text to firebase [but only when I use a image is when my post is uploaded to firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M10CD.png)

What am I missing from this code that's not allowing my `viewmodel.text` to upload to firebase and How do I rewrite this code to upload my user text to firebase

This is the uploadPostViewModel I have the text listed as a string but yet the data is not being uploaded to firebase as if it not listed what am I missing from this code that's not allowing my data to be uploaded to firebase

```
class UploadPostViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var didUploadPost = false
    @Published var error: Error?
    @Published var profileImage: Image?
    @Published var text = ""
    @Published var selectedImage: PhotosPickerItem? {
        didSet { Task { await loadImage(fromItem: selectedImage) } }
    }
    
    private var uiImage: UIImage?
    
    func uploadPost(caption: String) async throws {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        if let image = uiImage {
            
            
                let imageUrl = try await ImageUploader.uploadImage(image: image , type: .post)
           
                let post = Post(
                    ownerUid: uid,
                    text: text, caption: caption,
                    likes: 0,
                    replyCount: 23, image: imageUrl!,
                    timestamp: Timestamp()
                )
                
                try await PostService.uploadPost(post)
                self.didUploadPost = true
            
            }
        }
        
        
        func loadImage(fromItem item: PhotosPickerItem?) async {
            guard let item = item else { return }
            
            guard let data = try? await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) else { return }
            guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
            self.uiImage = uiImage
            self.profileImage = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        }
    }
```

```
struct PostUIView: View {
 @State var captionText = ""
       
       @StateObject var viewModel = UploadPostViewModel()
       @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
      
       @Binding var tabIndex: Int
       
       private var user: Userss? {
           return ThirdUserService.shared.currentUser
       }
       var body: some View {
           NavigationStack {
               VStack {
                   HStack(alignment: .top) {
                       RectangularImageSize(user: user, size: .small)
                       
                       VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                           Text(user?.username ?? "")
                               .fontWeight(.semibold)
                           
                           TextField("Type Something", text: $viewModel.text, axis: .vertical)
                       }
                       .font(.footnote)
                       
                       Spacer()
                       
                       if !viewModel.text.isEmpty {
                           Button {
                               viewModel.text = ""
                           } label: {
                               Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                   .resizable()
                                   .frame(width: 12, height: 12)
                                   .foregroundColor(.gray)
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   
                   Spacer()
               }
               .padding()
               .toolbar {
                   ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                       Button("Cancel") {
                           dismiss()
                       }
                       .font(.subheadline)
                       .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                   }
                   
                   ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                       Button("Post") {
                           Task {
                               try await viewModel.uploadPost()
                               dismiss()
                           }
                       }
                       .opacity(viewModel.text.isEmpty ? 0.5 : 1.0)
                       .disabled(viewModel.text.isEmpty)
                       .font(.subheadline)
                       .fontWeight(.semibold)
                       .foregroundStyle(Color.green)
                   }
               }
               .onDisappear { tabIndex = 0 }
               
           }
       }
   }
```

**This is the PostService**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class PostService {
    
 
        static func uploadPost(_ post: Post) async throws {
    guard let postData = try? Firestore.Encoder().encode(post) else { return }
    do {
    let ref = try await FirestoreConstants.PostsCollection.addDocument(data: postData)
    try await updateUserFeedsAfterPost(postId: ref.documentID)
    } catch {
        print("---> \(error)")
    }
}
    
    static func fetchPost(withId id: String) async throws -> Post {
        let postSnapshot = try await FirestoreConstants.PostsCollection.document(id).getDocument()
        let post = try postSnapshot.data(as: Post.self)
        return post
    }
    
    static func fetchUserPosts(user: Userss) async throws -> [Post] {
        let snapshot = try await FirestoreConstants.PostsCollection.whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: user.id).getDocuments()
        var posts = snapshot.documents.compactMap({try? $0.data(as: Post.self )})
        
        for i in 0 ..< posts.count {
            posts[i].user = user
        }
        
        return posts
    }
```

**Post**

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase

struct Post: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let ownerUid: String
    let text: String
    let caption: String
    var likes: Int
    var replyCount: Int
    let image: String?
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    
    var user: Userss?
    
    var didLike: Bool? = false
}
```

**FirebaseConstants**

```
import Firebase

struct FirestoreConstants {
    private static let Root = Firestore.firestore()
    
    
    static let UserCollection = Root.collection("users")
    static let PostsCollection = Root.collection("posts")
    static let FollowersCollection = Root.collection("followers")
    static let FollowingCollection = Root.collection("following")

    static let RepliesCollection = Root.collection("replies")
    
    static let ActivityCollection = Root.collection("activity")
    static let MessagesCollection = Root.collection("messages")

}
```

Comment: This is identical to the last time you asked this question. In the code included, you have guard statements that prevent `uploadPost` from being reached unless you have an image.

Comment: how do I rewrite it to fix the problem @jnpdx

Comment: Remove the guard statements that prevent uploadPost from happening unless you have an image

Comment: check my updated code @jnpdx

Comment: Don't force unwrap. Just don't upload the image if you don't have one, but don't prevent going through to `uploadPost(post)`. Do you know how to use `if let`?

Comment: if let remove the error but the text post still not uploading to firebase

Comment: `try await PostService.uploadPost(post)` is still inside `if let` tied to the image. It will never get called if there isn't an image. You need to structure your code so that `Post` has an optional image and you can still create the post and call `uploadPost` on it even if there isn't an `image`.

Comment: can you show me a example @jnpdx

Comment: Change `let image: String` to `let image: String?`. Then, only include an image if you have one. Call `uploadPost(post)` regardless of whether you have an image. Make sure that your `if let` statement doesn't prevent it from happening. Use the debugger or print statements to see if the code is going where you expect it to

Comment: isn't uploadPost(post) already that im not understanding I already have that listed what is there to change @jnpdx

Comment: You are only calling `uploadPost(post)` if you have an image. You have an `if let` that surrounds it that guarantees you won't get there if you don't have an image. You can't create a `Post` without an `image` either because the property is non-Optional.

Comment: okay I changed Image? in post and still not uploading the text what do I have to changed in the uploadpostviewmodel @jnpdx

Comment: You still have your `uploadPost` inside an `if let` that is only true if you have an image. Create and upload the `Post` _outside_ that `if let`. Use the debugger or print statements to see where the code is going when it runs.

Comment: how to place the uploadPost out the if let and  the print error didn't give me nothing in the debugger @jnpdx

Comment: Take you lines that start with `let post = Post` and `try await PostService.uploadPost(post)` and move them _outside_ the `if let`. Change the `Post` init to use `image: nil` instead of `image: imageUrl!`. If that works, we can go from there

Comment: I received a error in my FeedCell when I tried to post the image in the updated code above why is that @jnpdx

Comment: Because you are force unwrapping the image. Please review the Swift documentation on how to deal with Optionals. And please don’t change the question after you had already gotten and accepted an answer.

Comment: Use an `if let` surrounding the KFImage. If you have trouble with that, start a _new_ question

Comment: I've rolled back the changes you've made that changed the content of the question completely after receiving an answer for the _original_ question. To solve your _new_ error, please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're only calling `PostService.uploadPost()` if you have an image.

Instead, you can make your `image` property `Optional` on your `Post` and make sure that you call `uploadPost` regardless of if the image is present:

```
func uploadPost(caption: String) async throws {
  guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
  var imageUrl: String? = nil
  if let image = uiImage {
     imageUrl = try await ImageUploader.uploadImage(image: image , type: .post)
  }
           
  let post = Post(
    ownerUid: uid,
    text: text, caption: caption,
    likes: 0,
    replyCount: 23, 
    image: imageUrl,
    timestamp: Timestamp()
  )
                
  try await PostService.uploadPost(post)
```